# ResourceClosedError with mysql, sqlalchemy and celery

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, celery, mysql-python

I am using sqlalchemy in an app where celery tasks use a scoped session to interact with mysql.

db.py

```
engine = create_engine(
    'mysql://root:pass@localhost/testdb?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0',
    pool_recycle=3600)

db_session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))
```

I use a celery task that's scheduled to periodically run (with celery beat) and create a TaskSet of the task that uses the session

```
@celery.task
def create_tasks():    
    tasks = []
    tasks.append(charge_now.subtask((tid,)))
    job = TaskSet(tasks)
    job.apply_async()
```

Following is task the TaskSet is made of

```
@celery.task
def charge_now(tid):
    transaction = db_session.query(TransactionInfo).get(tid)
```

(I am doing an insert afterwards. I omitted that and some logic from the code for clarity)

Following is the error I get

> Task tasks.charge_now[bf199346-0862-4709-95b8-053859ed5a6f] raised
>   exception: ResourceClosedError('This result object does not return
>   rows. It has been closed automatically.',)

I understand it's an issue created by multiple threads trying to share the same session but can someone point to how to fix this?

Comment: I've had overlooked session remove. I subclassed Celery Task and made after_return do db_session.remove() ([see how to do it](http://prschmid.blogspot.com/2013/04/using-sqlalchemy-with-celery-tasks.html)). Since it didn't work I gave up TaskSet and used a plain delay to summon the task. When that failed, I tried just calling charge_now() method from create_tasks() task. It didn't help until I ran worker with --concurrency=1

Comment: 1 AM and it's showing on my work. I added db_session.remove() at the end of charge_now() method and it works fine without crippling --concurrency=1.

Comment: Is your solution fix that issue up? I have met the same issue when i using flask-rq with flask-sqlalchemy. while I have no idea whether it was caused by sqlalchemy session conflict. According to your question. Some scenarios are same with yours.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not update here with what worked for me. I don't exactly remember but the problem was with session not closing appropriately. I'm doing a session close with a context manager in final code.

Comment: Could you show me some example codes on it? was it caused by  unclose session correctly?

Comment: Hope this helps https://github.com/mozilla/ichnaea/blob/bce13eb10c6a6d2bea45188c1bf008811966186d/ichnaea/db.py

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it.